# Is Iptables blocking outgoing ssh connections?

Tags: ssh, firewall, arch-linux, iptables

I have been trying to do pulls from github and it keeps hanging. My iptables rules have no rules which block outgoing traffic but I cannot connect to github using either ssh or http. I can't even connect to the ssh server over localhost. When I disable the firewall this problem goes away. I know the ssh server is allowed incoming because I connect to the server solely through ssh.

Here is the output of my `iptables -nvL` :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
   92  6872 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9418
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    1    44 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 50 packets, 5664 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I don't know what is going on here, it seems to me that outgoing packets should be allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need accept rules for established connections.  Normally the first rule would be in this form.

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

You also appear to missing rules to accept the ICMP packets necessary for IP to work well.

```
-A INPUT -p 1 --icmp-type 3/4 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Needed ICMP types"
-A INPUT -p 1 --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Needed ICMP types"
```

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, it looks like you are dropping the return packages. Add the following rule to your iptables:

`/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

That accepts returning packages.